# How to pass php variable (id) using button going to other form

Tags: php

Sorry for kinda idiot, I just want to ask if possible to pass a php variable using button.
for example I have a list of records with update, contact, delete buttons at the end of row. when I click the update it will go to update page where i can get the id that passes through the button.

```
foreach($director->results() as $director){

                        $id = $director->id;

                        echo "<tr>  
                                <td>$director->director</td>  
                                <td>$director->agent_name</td>  
                                <td>$director->apz_account</td>  
                                <td>$director->api_account</td>  
                                <td>$director->wupos_tid</td>  
                                <td>$director->translink_tid</td>  
                                <td>$director->island_name</td>  
                                <td>$director->region</td>  
                                <td>$director->province</td>
                                <td>$director->city</td>
                                <td>$director->address</td>
                                <td>$director->landmark</td>
                                <td width='200'>

<button class='btn btn-mini btn-info' value='$director->apz_account'>Update</button>
<button class='btn btn-mini btn-info'>Contact</button>
<button class='btn btn-mini btn-info'>delete</button>"; //end the echo command

}
```

Comment: You should use `<form>` to achieve this. When sending your form you can retrieve the value by using $_POST superglobal. [Awesome documentation here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to work with `<form>` and passing the id of director with an hidden `<input>` to the page in which you want to do the update

try this way:

```
<form method="POST" action="yourPage.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="id_director" value="<?= $id ?>" />

    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

then in **`yourPage.php`**

```
$id_director = $_POST['id_director'];

//do your query
"UPDATE director set foo = 'foo' where id = $id_director";
```

hope this helps

Comment: to add to this, every single input or button as you are using needs a name to identify the field. Fortunately as you only need to know the value, the name of the buttons can be identical. `<button name=id value=myvalue>`

Comment: here's my work. <form method='post' action='update_sub_agent.php'><input type='hidden' name='row_id' value=\"$id\" /><button type='submit' class='btn btn-mini btn-info' value='Update'>Update</button>

Comment: try this: <form method='post' action='update_sub_agent.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='row_id' value='$id' /><input type='submit' class='btn btn-mini btn-info' value='Update'>Update</input>

Comment: what error do you get? or what value do you receive in `update_sub_agent.php`?

Comment: i received id number 32 only even I click the value 33 i still get 32

Comment: that's weird.. are you sure the value that you send it actually 32? You can debug it with chrome

Comment: show you my actual code. is there any error i made? `<form method='post' action='update_sub_agent.php'> <input type='text' name='row_id' value='$id' /><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\" />`

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the submit button, trigger an event in jquery

then get the id of that row using the `attr` property and pass it as a query string to that php page and from that php page you can get the value of that id and you can do any manipulations

For ex:

```
$("#button").click(function(){

var id=$(this).attr("id");
//Use jquery's ajax method here to

$.ajax(
                {
                    // The link we are accessing.
                    url: "your url?id="+id,

                    // The type of request.
                    type: "get",

                    // The type of data that is getting returned.
                    dataType: "html",

                    error: function(){
                        ShowStatus( "AJAX - error()" );

                        // Load the content in to the page.
                        jContent.html( "<p>Page Not Found!!</p>" );
                    },

                    beforeSend: function(){
                        ShowStatus( "AJAX - beforeSend()" );
                    },

                    complete: function(){
                        ShowStatus( "AJAX - complete()" );
                    },

                    success: function( strData ){
                        ShowStatus( "AJAX - success()" );

                        // Load the content in to the page.
                        jContent.html( strData );
                    }
                }                           
                );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this make a function and then do like this

```
<button onclick="updateme('<?php echo $director->apz_account ?>')" class='btn btn-mini btn-info' value='$director->apz_account'>Update</button>
```

now the function is

```
function updateme(id){

//alert(id); just to get the id
window.location.href = 'your_page_url.php?id='+id;

}
```

make your code like this when you go to **our_page_url.php** use header there to load your current page

do your code likes this and then you get alert...
once you get alert page reload with given href  and do your  query
to complete the update...!!..
**NOTE**:-here no need to use value attr. because you get value in function

```
echo "<button onclick=\"updateme('".$director->id ."')\"  class='btn btn-mini btn-info' value=".$director->id ." >Update</button>";
```

Comment: it didn't pass to other page where function updateme() function located

Comment: @JaysonLacson i try it right now and it work for me...!!onen the alert comment and check that you get id or not

Comment: here my code <button onclick=\"updateme('<?php echo $director->id ?>')\" class='btn btn-mini btn-info' value='$director->id'>Update 1</button>